# How to use Dependency Injection with the Facade pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, autofac

I am using `autofac` in my UWP application.

I am using the [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern for my backend and it is represented by an `IFacade` interface.

```
public interface IFacade 
{
    /* forwards view-models' calls to different parts of the backend */
}
```

The view-models of my UWP application are using an implementation of `IFacade` whose concrete implementation is resolved through `autofac` in the UWP's `App` instance.

```
public class App : Application
{
    ...

    private IFacade InitializeDependencies()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //  Registers all the platform-specific implementations of services.
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<LoggingService>().As<ILoggingService>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<SQLitePlatformService>().As<ISQLitePlatformService>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<DiskStorageService>().As<IDiskStorageService>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<IdentityProviderFactoryService>().As<IIdentityProviderFactoryService>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<DefaultVaultService>().As<IVaultService>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<LocationService>().As<ILocationService>().SingleInstance();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<NavigationService>().As<INavigationService>().SingleInstance();

        //  Registers all the dependencies of the Backend project.
        var backendDependencies = new Dependencies();
        backendDependencies.Setup(containerBuilder);

        //  Resolves the IFacade.
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();

        return backendDependencies.ResolveFacade(lifetimeScope);
    }
```

I have a lot of services in my backend and my implementation of `IFacade` ends up with that horrific constructor referencing a lot of services' interfaces, something would make Uncle Bob cringe.

```
internal sealed Facade : IFacade
{
    public Facade(ISessionService sessionService, IEntitiesRepository entitiesRepository, ISynchronizationService synchronizationService, IVaultService vaultService, IIdentityProviderFactoryService identityProviderFactoryService, IDemoTapeService demoTapeService, IDiskStorageService diskStorageService)
    {
        /* Saves the references as read-only fields. */
    }
}
```

**Question**

Contrary to the ServiceLocator, using DI forces us to make all the dependencies that are needed visible. I am not sure if I am using the Dependency Injection properly.

What can I do so that my constructor of my `Facade` class does not have that many parameters?

**Solutions tried**

1. Properties

I could change the `Facade` class and inject the services through public properties. I am not fond of lots of `public get / set` as my `IFacade` contract would now indicate that those properties could be changed after the `Facade` implementation is created, which is not something I want to support (and debug).

2. Aggregate interfaces

Another option would be to aggregate interfaces together (something that I call the `SomethingContext` classes) but then it is harder to understand what these groups of interfaces would mean.

3. Inject a ServiceLocator that is not static in the `Facade` constructor

The last solution that seems more acceptable (well... acceptable to me) would be to use DI to inject a non-static ServiceLocator. It is kind of solution 2). However, I know the ServiceLocator is something that is [frowned upon](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: DI with constructor injection is fine for all dependencies you really need. I recommend using property injection only for optional dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So one another approach is to create some smaller Facade Services and then inject those services to the main facade.

For example you can create such smaller facade for `INavigationService` and `ILocationService`:

```
public class GeographyService : IGeographyService
{
    public GeographyService(
        INavigationService navigationService, 
        ILocationService locationService)
    { 
    }
}
```

The same is true for `ISQLitePlatformService` and `DiskStorageService`:

```
public class StorageService : IStorageService 
{
    public StorageService(
        ISQLitePlatformService databaseService, 
        DiskStorageService diskStorageService)
    { 
    }
}
```

That's of course only an example of an idea.

Such an approach is generally considered better than aggregate services with all the dependencies aggregated (http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html) or ServiceLocator (anti-)pattern. You can also read some thoughts about it here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/

Comment: From the links you provided me, the following one stands out :) http://peterspattern.com/dependency-injection-and-class-inheritance/